# Where can I find a replacement cover plate for a triple pushbutton switch?

Tags: switch, garage-door-opener

I'm looking to replace a Push Button Wall Plate.  I can't seem to find one that only has spots for three buttons.  Most have six spots. (three sets of two buttons).  These are standard size push buttons (like you see for lights in a house) which I don't believe I could replace as they are push buttons that open garage doors.

I'm looking for a cheap wall plate (preferably under $10). The common tan color or white would also be preferred.  I've checked Lowe's and Home Depot and googled around a little, but can't seem to find a replacement. I've added a quick sketch of my situation.

[image: Broken and Unbroken Wall Plate]

Comment: I would get a blank and just drill it.

Answer (score 3):

Pull your switch out, look at it to see who the manufacturer is, and contact them or check their website.  Usually when a manufacturer makes an oddball like this, they also make the cover plates to match.

Answer (score 0):

First, I thank you for that picture. Hilarious!

I found the switch plates you're looking for, but it looks like you have to buy the switches with it. They're LED lit push-buttons, and they're EXPENSIVE, and generally non-US for some reason. You may want to go with the suggestion to make one from a blank.

Here's one example of my Bing search for "3 button wall switch":
https://www.sparkydirect.com.au/p/5245248/clipsal-saturn---3-gang-pushbutton-led-switch-pure-white-4063pblpw-4063pbl.html